# Need Help On Phonegap List View

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

Hii i am doing a simple phone gap application.i want to display my data in list view in phonegap using ajax.but i am facing one problem in listview.my list view showing only one value at a time.means i want to show all titles in list view.but it showing only one title..how can i show all databse calumns value in listview.how can i loop it.pls help.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://url/display.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){

            $('#list').append('<li >'+data.title+'</li>');
             $("#list").listview("refresh");
            alert('Data successfully display');

        },
        error: function(){
            alert('There was an error');
        }
    });
```

#html

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div class="example-wrapper">
       <ul data-role="listview"  id="list" data-divider-theme="a" data-inset="true</ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

## php

```
<?php
include_once('config/config.php');

$sql="select * from myapp";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

{
$array = $row;

}

echo json_encode($array);

 ?>
```

Comment: can you post your response too or else try to use each to iterate your title from data response

Comment: i am geting list view.but it is in one row..not one bye one..i think i have to use for loop..but i dont know how to use.pls help

Comment: check <ul> tag it is not closed correctly.

Comment: sorry i am bigner.can u just show me.

Comment: list view showing only one title at a time...i have more than 10 titles in databse..but it showing only last title.

Comment: so you need to use for-each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently getting one row of data using your PHP code, I have modified your code,

```
<?php
include_once('config/config.php');

$sql="select * from myapp";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

{
$array[] = $row;

}

echo json_encode($array);

 ?>
```

And ajax code like this,

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://url/display.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            $('#list').append('<li >'+data[i].title+'</li>');
}
             $("#list").listview("refresh");
            alert('Data successfully display');

        },
        error: function(){
            alert('There was an error');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not close `<ul>` tag. Change like this,

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div class="example-wrapper">
       <ul data-role="listview"  id="list" data-divider-theme="a" data-inset="true">
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check this too,

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://url/display.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            var li_tag='';
            $(data).each(function( index,value ) {
               console.log( index + ": " + value );
               li_tag=li_tag+'<li>'+value+'</li>'
            });
            $('#list').append(li_tag);
             $("#list").listview("refresh");
            alert('Data successfully display');

        },
        error: function(){
            alert('There was an error');
        }
    });
```

Comment: i did..but still same prob.

Comment: Post your response then only it can able to give correct solution